# Unhandled Exception with Google Cloud Vision API and Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-cloud-vision

I am working on Xamarin Forms to create a native application. I am new to Xamarin and as well as google cloud vision API. I am trying to create ImageAnnotatorClient object (client) by passing it channel as parameter to the Create() method. However, it doesn't create the client and gives this exception.

Exception:

Unhandled Exception:

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices' threw an exception.

Code: 
[image]

So, could be a problem of passing the JSON file incorrectly? I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. If it is not that could any please help me figure out how to resolve this exception?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ghalib

Comment: I'm afraid the Google Cloud Client libraries aren't supported on Xamarin. Even if you get this working locally on your dev machine, you'll definitely have problems when you try to use it on a mobile device. We use gRPC which has a native component, and which only ships for Windows/Mac/Linux x86/x64 at the moment.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the full exception details though, including any nested exception within the TypeInitializationException. While it's not something we'd probably fix anyway (as this is an unsupported platform) it's good to know what the failure modes are.

Comment: I suspect it's basically this issue though: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/1230